# Initialize value of a checkbox from servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, checkbox

I am woking on a Eclipse project in which in my JSP file I can add items. Each item has a status. To choose the status, I implemented a checkbox.

When the checkbox is checked, I store the value 1 in my DB.

I implemented the modification of an item and I would like to check (or not) my checkbox depending on the value stored in my DB.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="active" >active
```

How can I check the checkbox from my servlet in case the item in modification has a status = 1 ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuption

Your item/entity/object has a property named **status** of type Integer that will return 1 if the status is "active".
The item list is already stored in a scope no less than **request**.

#### Here is one way to do it with JSTL:

In your jsp,

```
<c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="item">
  <c:if test="${item.status ne 1}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="0">active
  </c:if>

  <c:if test="${item.status eq 1}">
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked="checked"> active
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

#### If you are not using JSTL

Change the above JSTL tag to java snippet, which is not recommended.